# Connection Failed from Client to Server in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am new to node js and socket.io, i am trying basic example of socket.io in my windows machine.

**Server Code**

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Client Code**

```
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
  socket.on('connect', function () {
        alert('connect');
    });

    socket.on('error', function (data) {
        console.log(data || 'error');
    });

    socket.on('connect_failed', function (data) {
        console.log(data || 'connect_failed');
    });
</script>
```

In the above script client can not connect to the server (in console connect_failed was logged), but in the same time server side following was shown,

```
    info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"news","args":[{"hello":"world"}]}
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t=1
374168523063
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168533064&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168556555&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168576586&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168596600&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168616640&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t
=1374168636656&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t=1
374168523063
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 8::
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t=1
374168663072
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 8::
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t=1
374168690890
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 8::
   debug - set close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
   debug - xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7?t=1
374168710895
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ALB0omsm3E2ZvPMn02x7
```

How can i fix the error in the above scripts to successfully run the basic example of socket.io?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the socket.io settings as per your requirements.
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

I also encountered the same problem and found that adding the below line solves the problem

```
io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);
```

Comment: Hi. This line of code saves my life. I wonder why it works. Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean it will only use xhr-pooling and not Websocket at all or when it is possible to use Websocket it will?

Comment: Akamai does not support websockets. This is fall back.

Answer (score 0):

Make a localhost.js file with this data:

```
var port = 80,
http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
socket = require('socket.io'),
app = function (req, res) {
  var url = req.url == '/' ? '/index.html' : req.url;
  fs.readFile(__dirname + url, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.end(data);
  });
},
httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port),
io = socket.listen(httpServer);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And a index.html file with this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="socket.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:80/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });

  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connect');
  });

  socket.on('error', function (data) {
    console.log(data || 'error');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

put socket.min.js in the same folder then run in cmd:

```
node localhost.js
```

Comment: it does work for me ... im running nodejs on a windows 7. Maybe you should reinstall / update nodejs and socket.io.

Comment: after am changing transport type to xhr, now working in my chrome and firefox :). Why?

Comment: how did you changed to xhr?

Comment: through `io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);`

Comment: with this setting you are not using sockets but ajax. that points toward some problem with your socket.io "installation"

Comment: What was the Installation Error? I have already re-installed all modules many times... And also tried the same in different machines(All are XP machines)...

Comment: can't tell ... all I can say is that it should work .. here is a zip file link so you make sure there are no errors: http://sites.google.com/site/rafaelcastrocouto/download/basic.zip

Comment: I have tested with your code @rafaelcastrocouto. But the same problem.. The following line from server
   `debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"news","args":[{"news":"hello world"}]}` But in client side no action received...

Comment: try io.set('log level', 0);

Comment: The same problem still :( :(